# How do i make this form same on all browsers?

Tags: css, html, cross-browser

**Problem**

So i have a form that displays different on Firefox than it does on Chrome. Everything is fine apart from the last two items, Max-Budget and Min-Budget.

**Chrome**

This is the desired look.

[image]

**FireFox**

This is how it looks on firefox

[image]

What could i do to make them look the same? Is this just because i haven't left enough room or is there different CSS i should be using?

Comment: Side-note: "Choose you colour" should be "Choose *your* colour", and you should use either "colour" or "color" but be consistent in the one you use ;)

Comment: You should probably show the code that you used to create/style those last two items

Comment: This is a strange one, It is difficult to see exactly what is going wrong without using the Chrome or Firefox developer tools. Perhaps you could provide some more information.

Comment: I'd try running a validator on the markup, maybe there is some error in the markup not the CSS

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol Thank you, I am pretty slack with stuff like this until i'm ready to go live. Good spot though, thanks again! Might have to lose the colour part anyway as it's not fully supported by all browsers yet! I really wish they would get their acts together!

Comment: Another side-note: http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/#white-on-%23bbb (your background colour has been approximated here)... 1.9 is not a good ratio!

Comment: There are a lot of articles on the 'net about these issues, most of them are related to the baseline and how to line things up in the different browsers. But, without a link or a fiddle, anything we say will just be a wild guess.

Comment: @gvee, what is this....looks interesting! I am still pretty new to web development, and this like like a neat little tool i will be adding to my process! Thanks

Comment: @DanCundy you should always be mindful of the contrast ratio of your text and backgrounds as not everyone's eyesight is as good as yours! There's a bit of a recommendation on the W3.org site (http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/#visual-audio-contrast-contrast). consider this example (http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/#%23128-on-%23123) - it's pretty hard to read that blue text on that blue background, eh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your labels are `float:left`. You should also add `clear:left` so that in a case like this (where the label is a bit longer) the following label won't float with it.

Comment: I think you might be right! It does look like that, i will test later once i finish work!

Comment: Spot on, Thank you! :) Clear:Both on the second set of labels did it!